# highlight all routes (google maps) within a specific circle radius

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am using Google Maps Javascript API v3,

What i would like to do is to highlight all routes within a specific circle radius when choosing a point in the map (point coordinates and circle radius are input parameters).

I tried to use the Directions Services and i did manage to display all possible routes when origin and destination points and travelMode are specified and the provideRouteAlternatives option is set to true.

When setting the origin point to be the cirle center, is there way to set multiple destinations points (points on the circle perimeter), and then loop over availables routes and highlight them using Directions Service?

P.S.: i am not trying to draw a circle around a point but to highlight all roads within the circle radius.

Thanks.

Comment: You can highlight roads using the [styles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapTypeStyle) but I can't think of a way to do that only within a specific area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *just-for-fun* answer.

Not really an answer because it really feels like a dirty little hack, and also I am not sure to understand what exactly you are trying to highlight (is it **all streets** or the **results of a Directions request** — this is unclear from your question).

But basically, I added 2 maps. The first one is the base map and the other one is positioned on top of the first one, with a border radius, and styles applied.

I then synchronize both maps so that they both move relatively (when panning / zooming).

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.51, -0.12);

var styles = [{
    "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ff3380"
    }]
}];

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var roundedMapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    styles: styles
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
var roundedMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-rounded"), roundedMapOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function () {

    roundedMap.setCenter(map.getCenter());
});

google.maps.event.addListener(roundedMap, 'drag', function () {

    map.setCenter(roundedMap.getCenter());
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {

    roundedMap.setCenter(map.getCenter());
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {

    roundedMap.setZoom(map.getZoom());
});
```

*Note on the use of the `idle` event listener*:

If you are dragging the map very quickly, sometimes the sync is kind of lost. So with the `idle` event listener, the maps are re-synced after a drag.

*Note that I added the below CSS rule to **hide the copyright on the rounded map**:*

```
#map-rounded .gm-style-cc {
    display: none;
}
```

This is clearly **against [Google Maps TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)** but since it is still there on the base map, I would think this is a *fair* or *acceptable* misuse of the API :)

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/ooq7wcjc/)</kbd>

Comment: Is it also possible to get details of those highlighted routes? Not actually the geography but maybe as array of "svg line trace" or some other code notation which can point to specific lines, if we see them purely as 2d lines and not as roads.

Comment: I don't think you can and will ever be able to do that with the API. Other sources might be available though.