# Creating a 'Magnifying Glass Effect' for Google Maps using API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I am able to zoom into Google Maps using the normal Google Maps API features.  For example I draw a bounding box on the map, and the Google API will zoom in by the amount set by the default value.  But zooming in manually all the time on a map with lots of tracks is very time consuming as you are continually zooming in and out looking for certain features.

I am hoping someone has implemented something similar that might put me on the right track.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28432226/1238965

Comment: Thanks.  I am making progress and every bit helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution approach, which would require two map instances,

1. Main map - 1 Instance which has listeners of hover/click based on [event listener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-domListener) to get latLong like [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-click-latlng).
2. Overlay map - 2 Instance which takes the latlong from map -1 and [creates latlong bounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) to [fit](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.fitBounds) the overlay map with desired [zoom level.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom)
3. Position the overlay map on Main map with [MapCanvasProjection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#MapCanvasProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel)

Alternatively you can [use static maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start), instead of step 2.

Comment: I was thinking along similar lines but without your depth of detail, so I may try something like you suggest.  It is not going to be very easy because I need to zoom into the map region that has polylines drawn on the map as well.

Comment: Yeah. If you have polylines, better to convert them to [data layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) and handle it with [geoJSON](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) adding data to map - 2 as geoJSON [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson)